# Why does my violin sound... strange?

Tags: violin

Ok, when I pass the bow in one of the strings if I focus myself I can hear a strange sound (like the sound when you pass the nails in a green blackboard). At the beginning, I thought that it was because the bow didn't have enough rosin so I put more. After a couple of minutes I could hear the sound again so I cleaned the strings with cotton and alcohol (my teacher told me to do so) but after a while, I could hear the sound again.

If you don't pay too much attention then the sound it's undetectable.

What could i do in order to prevent this?

NOTE: I'm a beginner.

NOTE: When I say in one fo the strings I mean in the E string (sorry).

EDIT: I don't know why it suddenly appeared again on my notififications but I want to say thank you all for your responses! Back then I had a cheap violin but I changed it a couple of months ago! I'm still beginner (I'm learning to shift and my vibrato sounds ... not like an animal dying.) but I'm doing my best.

:)

Comment: Don't worry about it. As a beginner you will be making even stranger sounds on the way to being a player. Stick with it, make fun out of the weird noises, and carry on playing. If your teacher thought it was life-threatening, s/he would probably mentioned it.

Answer (score 3):

You write "one of the strings" but don't mention which one.  E strings in particular have a tendency to whistle: they are usually the only unwound strings and thus are quite thinner than the others, giving the bow less grip.

For any string (or note) there can be resonances due to loose parts on the violin.  For example, if you have a fine tuner turned out all the way, its screw becomes loose and may buzz.  A fine tuner turned in too far might touch the top of the violin and buzz or worse.  The cure in either case is to use the tuning peg in the direction where the fine tuner went too far in order to be able to dial the fine tuner back into more of a middle position.

Are the screws on the chin rest (assuming it is in) both firm?  When you gently shake the violin, is there a noise?  Sometimes things like the sound post or bass beam have come loose, or the violin's frame has opened somewhere.  Loose wooden parts tend to require a luthier's attention.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you are hearing the friction between the bow and the strings underlying the note itself.

If you are using inexpensive strings, particularly gut, the noise could be more noticeable. Don't cheap out on strings! They are expensive, but with care (wiping down after each session) they should last a while. The quality of the string is a large factor that makes up the sound of a violin, so it is important to get the best strings you can afford.

Work on the speed of your bowing combined with the right pressure. If you are bowing too slowly and pressing too hard, you will make a more scratchy sound. When playing lightly or softly, ease up on the pressure. This will take some experimenting but you will soon learn to get the right touch.

Good luck, have fun playing and rest if you're feeling too frustrated and come back to it later. I'm sure your teacher will be able to help you solve this.

All the best.

By the way, I've been playing thirty years and find the violin to be an amazingly beautiful and expressive instrument. Keep it up and you'll have a friend for life!